# How Keypad Automation Using Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, keypad

In the web page, I click on the `textfield` a keypad is displayed. I have tried to capture the values ​​of each button in a list, but when I use the `getText ()` it does not return anything, and when I use the `getAttribute ("value")` it returns `null`. I also tried `JavaScriptExecutor` and it doesn't return anything too...

Comment: getAttribute() returns the value of a type attribute and null when there is none. Can you show how you implemented the buttons on the image?

Comment: Can you please show us the HTML code.

Comment: Thank you all! I solved it yesterday.